# sealert returning different context than ls -Z

Tags: security, centos, selinux

We have an internal application that was made that uses the TinyButStrong plugin to generate an excel spreadsheet. I keep receiving the following error when generating the spread sheet

```
TinyButStrong Error OpenTBS Plugin: Method Flush() cannot overwrite the target file 'tmp_filespace_ngp/label_20160407104148_337902988.xlsx'. This may not be a valid file path or the file may be locked by another process or because of a denied permission. The process is ending, unless you set NoErr property to true.
```

If i set selinux to permissive the excel spreadsheet is created successfully, so to me this appears to be an selinux issue.

I have tried chcon httpd_sys_rw_content_t on the top level directory TopLevelDirectory/ and received the same error.

Using `sealert -a /var/log/audit.log`

I receive

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from write access on the directory tmp_filespace_ngp Additional Information:

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
Target Objects                tmp_filespace_ngp [ dir ]
Source                        httpd
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/httpd
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          <Unknown>
Source RPM Packages           httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     intWeb1.localdomain
Platform                      Linux intWeb1.localdomain 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1
                              SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   2
First Seen                    2016-04-07 10:33:21 EDT
Last Seen                     2016-04-07 10:41:48 EDT
```

Ran `ls -Z /TopLevelDirectory/`

`unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tmp_filespace_ngp`

Any ideas would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue with

```
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

This doesn't seem like the best fix, but i will look into finding the correct script and applying the correct context to it.